# ServletContext.log() not logging

Tags: gwt, logging, guice, slf4j, servlets

Log output of my `RemoteServiceServlet` (GWT) is not shown in Logfiles or Stdout when using `getServletContext().log("anything");`

For dependency injection I use **Google Guice**. For my own log output I use **slf4j-jdk14**. I tried this in Tomcat 6 as well as in Jetty (GWT devmode).

To make it clear, my Servlet:

```
@Singleton
public class MyServiceServlet extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MyService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceServlet.class);
    private final ADependency dep;

    @Inject
    public MyServiceServlet(ADependency dep) {
        getServletContext().log("THIS IS NOT SHOWN IN MY LOGS");
        log.error("THIS IS SHOWN IN MY LOGS");
        this.dep = dep;
    }
}
```

So, where can I find the missing log output or where can I configure the ServletContext-Log?

Comment: note: it's very easy to reproduce this: just create a GWT app with "mvn archetype:generate", choose "241: remote -> gwt-maven-plugin", replace the return in greetServer(String) with "throw new ..." and start the app with "mvn clean install gwt:run". The client shows an error, but there is no log output on the server.

Comment: ok... I just created a new webapp with just a servlet and nothing else. I deployed it in tomcat and found the log output in localhost.2011-04-09.log.

Comment: java.util.logging, slf4j, log4j, ServletContext.log(), commons.logging, ...  I just want to see all errors in a single file!

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issues?

Answer (score 5):

The ServletContext.log method behavior is container specific. The method I have used to make it consistent is to wrap the ServletConfig passed in through init() in order to create a wrapped ServletContext which uses our own provided logger (Slf4j in this case).

```
public class Slf4jServletConfigWrapper implements ServletConfig {
  private final ServletConfig config;
  private final Logger log;

  public Slf4jServletConfigWrapper(Logger log, ServletConfig config) {
    this.log = log;
    this.config = config;
  }

  public ServletContext getServletContext() {
    return new ServletContext() {
      public void log(String message, Throwable throwable) {
        log.info(message, throwable);
      }

      public void log(Exception exception, String msg) {
        log.info(msg, exception);
      }

      public void log(String msg) {
        log.info(msg);
      }
...
```

[Full Slf4jServletConfigWrapper.java code](https://gist.github.com/3048784)

In your Servlet override the init() method to use the ServletConfig wrapper

```
public void init(final ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
  super.init(new Slf4jServletConfigWrapper(log, config));
}
```